# Avoid __TypeId__ and spring_json_header_types magic headers set by Spring Kafka

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I'm trying to configure Spring Kafka, so that events sent through `KafkaTemplate` don't include magic `__TypeId__` header.
From what I read in the documentation and online, the `JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS` should give me the desired result. But I'm not using Spring's `JsonSerializer`, instead I'm using `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer` in combination with `ByteArrayJsonMessageConverter`. So, I'm confused, where that header is being set in my case and how to disable it?

Below is my configuration in code:

```java
@TestConfiguration
public static class TestKafkaProducerConfig {

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, MyEvent> kafkaTemplate(
            @Value("${kafka.consumer.my-topic-name}") String topicName, EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka) {

        var template = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory(embeddedKafka));
        template.setDefaultTopic(topicName);

        var headerMapper = new SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper();
        headerMapper.setMapAllStringsOut(true);

        var messageConverter = new ByteArrayJsonMessageConverter();
        messageConverter.setHeaderMapper(headerMapper);

        template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, MyEvent> producerFactory(EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka) {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfig(embeddedKafka));
    }

    public Map<String, Object> producerConfig(EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka) {
        Map<String, Object> props = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafka);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class);
        props.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);
        return props;
    }
}
```

If I use `JsonSerializer`, then the `JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS` setting is respected, and I don't get the `__TypeId__` header set. But, then I can't use my customised `MessageConverter` with `SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper` and `mapAllStringsOut` which prevents another magic header `spring_json_header_types`.

My overall goal is to avoid Spring Kafka setting any magic headers, like `__TypeId__` and `spring_json_header_types`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was explained by @artem-bilan, it's not that easy to get rid of the `__TypeId__` when using `ByteArraySerializer` and `ByteArrayJsonMessageConverter`. So, I used `JsonSerializer` and `MessagingMessageConverter` instead.
Below is my configuration which produces Kafka events without any magic headers.

```java
@TestConfiguration
public static class TestKafkaProducerConfig {

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, MyEvent> kafkaTemplate(
            @Value("${kafka.consumer.my-topic-name}") String topicName, EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka) {

        var template = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory(embeddedKafka));
        template.setDefaultTopic(topicName);

        // Use SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper which does not add the json types header, `spring_json_header_types`.
        // The mapAllStringsOut when set to true, all string-valued headers will be converted to byte[] using
        // the charset property (default UTF-8).
        var headerMapper = new SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper();
        headerMapper.setMapAllStringsOut(true);

        var messageConverter = new MessagingMessageConverter();
        messageConverter.setHeaderMapper(headerMapper);

        template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, MyEvent> producerFactory(EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka) {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfig(embeddedKafka));
    }

    public Map<String, Object> producerConfig(EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafka) {
        Map<String, Object> props = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafka);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        props.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);
        return props;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those header are indeed populated from that converter. It delegated to the `typeMapper`:

```
this.typeMapper.fromClass(message.getPayload().getClass(), headers);
```

Where `DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper` has a logic around the mentioned `__TypeId__` header to add:

```
public void fromJavaType(JavaType javaType, Headers headers) {
    String classIdFieldName = getClassIdFieldName();
    if (headers.lastHeader(classIdFieldName) != null) {
        removeHeaders(headers);
    }

    addHeader(headers, classIdFieldName, javaType.getRawClass());
```

That `getClassIdFieldName()` is `AbstractJavaTypeMapper.DEFAULT_CLASSID_FIELD_NAME` by default.

So, with your current combination of the `ByteArraySerializer` and `ByteArrayJsonMessageConverter` there is no way to prevent that header to appear in the `ProducerRecord`. Unless you inject a custom `Jackson2JavaTypeMapper` with overridden `fromJavaType()` with an empty body.

You really can avoid it with a `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper` and its `setMapAllStringsOut(true)` and there won't be that `spring_json_header_types` extra header if all headers you are going to send is `String` or already a `byte[]`.

See this ctor `DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper, String... patterns)` and provide only those headers which you really need to send.

Comment: You can also use a `SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper` which does not add the json types header. We should probably add an option to the message converter to not add the type id header(s). Please open a new feature issue on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Artem and Gary. I'm not sure if I understood your suggestion correctly. I tried to use `new DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper("!__TypeId__", "!X-Custom-Header", "*");` and although it worked to filter out `X-Custom-Header` header, the `__TypeId__` was still there.
But I've now made it work by using `JsonSerializer` with `JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS` and `MessagingMessageConverter` with `SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper` and `setMapAllStringsOut(true)`. I'll describe it in a separate reply.

Comment: Sure! That also possible.